# .join() returns unexpected string

Tags: python

```
from random import randint
roomTypes = ['T|', 'M|', 'W|', 'H|', 'C|']
dungeonLayout = ''
for i in range(1,10):
    dungeonLayout = dungeonLayout.join(roomTypes[randint(0, 4)])
print('Room types are Temple |T|, Abandoned Military Base |M|, Wizard\'s Abodes |W|, House |H|, Church |C|')
print('_____________________________')
print('|' + dungeonLayout)
print('_____________________________')`
```

My code (which is shown above) is meant to return a random list of the rooms, this sort of works, however instead of the rooms being formatted like this:

```
|W|H|
```

it prints:

```
|WH||
```

I am curious as to why this is and was wondering if I'm using the `join` command wrong or if I should be using a different command altogether.

Comment: What will `'W|'.join('H|')` return?

Comment: @PeterWood I would expect it to return W|H|, however it returns WH||, im using python 3.5.2 if that helps

Comment: @Harvey given what `str.join` does, that doesn't seem like a reasonable expectation. Note that e.g. `','.join('foo')` is `'f,o,o'`.

Comment: @Harvey Would `dungeon_layout = '|' + '|'.join(random.choice(room_types) for _ in range(10)) + '|'` work?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I might be being blind, but why does the OP's code ignore `|` after each letter if it's joining by an empty string and then throw them all on at the end?

Comment: @jDo With a little modification it does, thank you loads, i see where i went wrong now, thanks again

Comment: @roganjosh it's not joining by an empty string, it's joining all of the strings in the iterable `'H|'` together using `'W|'`, which gives `'HW||'`. `'W|'.join('abc')` would give `'aW|bW|c'`.

Comment: `'W|'.join('H|')` does the following: iterate over elements from the argument, e.g. the two elements `'H'` and `'|'` that make up the string `'H|'`, then joint the these two elements with the string `'W|'`. Result: `'HW||'`. You want `'W|' + 'H|'`, which returns `'W|H|'`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not sure any of the glut of answers explains this. From first glance, `dungeonLayout = ''` prior to the join, it didn't make sense to me why it didn't work.

Comment: @roganjosh `dungeonLayout` modifies itself on each iteration, which means its no more `' '` in the next iteration and hence the problem.

Comment: @roganjosh just run it with `print(dungeonLayout)` in the loop and it should become obvious. Each iteration just wraps the two new characters around the existing string, one at each end.

Comment: I see it now after you first pointed it out, I was just referring to the explosion of answers that don't necessarily explain why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because of this line -

```
for i in range(1,10):
    dungeonLayout = dungeonLayout.join(roomTypes[randint(0, 4)])
```

You are modifying `dungeonLayout` and using it again to join the list.

What you should do -

```
dungeonLayout = ''.join([roomTypes[randint(0, 4)] for _ in range(10)])
```

Comment: is there any way to make this persistent because i want to save this information for later use in the program.

Answer (score 2):

`join` is described here https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join and in summary you use the `str` as the *glue* between each elements in a given *iterable*.

Since you want to basically create a list of "rooms", you could use a `randomRooms` list to store a list of random room types, and then use the `join` function just to save it out in the desired format. Note that you will have to still add a separator at the beginning and one at the end. Here the sample with minimal code diff to yours.

```
from random import randint
roomTypes = ['T', 'M', 'W', 'H', 'C']
randomRooms = []
for i in range(1,10):
    randomRooms.append(roomTypes[randint(0, 4)])
dungeonLayout = '|' + '|'.join(randomRooms) + '|'
print('Room types are Temple |T|, Abandoned Military Base |M|, Wizard\'s Abodes |W|, House |H|, Church |C|')
print('_____________________________')
print(dungeonLayout)
print('_____________________________')
```

Also on https://eval.in/750197

Answer (score 1):

```
dungeon_layout = '|' + ''.join(random.choice(room_types) for _ in range(15))
```

The code above replaces the for loop that I added and fixes the problem and returns the correct amount of rooms, credit goes towards @jDo, thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to mention that I changed `roomTypes = ['T|', 'M|', 'W|', 'H|', 'C|']` to `room_types = ['T', 'M', 'W', 'H', 'C']` before I wrote the comment so `dungeon_layout = '|' + '|'.join(random.choice(room_types) for _ in range(10)) + '|'` produced `'|W|T|T|T|T|C|W|T|T|T|'`. Anyway, thanks, glad it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead you could use:

```
dungeonLayout = dungeonLayout + roomTypes[randint(0,4)]
```

This produces the "|T|C|M|T|M|C|C|C|C|" style output.

Answer (score 0):

my_str.join takes a collection (i.e. an iterable) of strings and returns those strings glued together with my_str, e.g.

```
"x".join(["1", "2", "3"])
# "1x2x3"
```

and e.g.

```
"x".join("A|")
# Ax|
```

because A| is a collection of "A" and "|".

You could maybe fix the loop but it's better to use a comprehension:

```
"".join(roomTypes[randint(0,4)] for i in range(1,10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`dungeonLayout = dungeonLayout.join(roomTypes[randint(0, 4)])`

you probably meant

`dungeonLayout += roomTypes[randint(0, 4)]`

Your current code will pick a random two-character string from roomTypes, treat it as a sequence of letters, and join it using the `dungeonLayout` variable as a delimiter, so the resulting string will be `someRoomType[0] + dungeonLayout + someRoomType[1]`.

You could also replace the complete 'for' loop with the following code, which expresses the idea of "take 10 random room types and join them together":

`from random import choices
dungeonLayout = ''.join(choices(roomTypes, k=10))`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are!

```
from random import randint
roomTypes = ['T|', 'M|', 'W|', 'H|', 'C|']
dungeonList = []
dungeonLayout = ""
for i in range(1,10):
    dungeonList.append(roomTypes[randint(0, 4)])

dungeonLayout = dungeonLayout.join(dungeonList)
print(dungeonLayout)
print('Room types are Temple |T|, Abandoned Military Base |M|, Wizard\'s Abodes |W|, House |H|, Church |C|')
print('_____________________________')
print('|' + dungeonLayout)
print('_____________________________')
```

Because you were joining each time, the program was getting confused.  Instead, I appended all the randoms into the list and then joined once.  If you join the same thing many times over, the computer will begin to error

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options...

The simplest is to use the `+` operator to concatenate each new room to your string:

```
dungeonLayout = dungeonLayout + roomTypes[randint(0, 4)]
```

But you're right, the join() method works slightly differently to this.  The argument should be a sequence of strings, which are concatenated using the string as the separator, i.e.

```
separator = '|'
myList = ['1', '2', '3']
print(separator.join(myList))
```

gives

```
1|2|3
```

So to use join() in your case:

```
from random import randint
roomTypes = ['T', 'M', 'W', 'H', 'C']
roomList = []
for i in range(1,10):
    roomList.append(roomTypes[randint(0, 4)])
dungeonLayout = '|'.join(roomList) + '|'
print('Room types are Temple |T|, Abandoned Military Base |M|, Wizard\'s Abodes |W|, House |H|, Church |C|')
print('_____________________________')
print('|' + dungeonLayout)
print('_____________________________')
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple edit, just change

```
dungeonLayout = dungeonLayout.join(roomTypes[randint(0, 4)])
```

to

```
dungeonLayout = dungeonLayout + roomTypes[randint(0, 4)]
```

Instead of using join, just use +
Here is full program

```
from random import randint
roomTypes = ['T|', 'M|', 'W|', 'H|', 'C|']
dungeonLayout = ''
for i in range(1,10):
    dungeonLayout = dungeonLayout + roomTypes[randint(0, 4)]
print('Room types are Temple |T|, Abandoned Military Base |M|, Wizard\'s Abodes |W|, House |H|, Church |C|')
print('_____________________________')
print('|' + dungeonLayout)
print('_____________________________')
rand1 = randint(0, 4)
```

Ex Output: |T|W|M|M|W|M|C|H|T|

Answer (score 0):

str.join(*iterable*)

Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the iterable *iterable*. The separator between elements is the string providing this method.

src=https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

so, from the explanation.. it returns the concatenation of strings in iterable *iterable*.

if you want your desired result, simply do:

`dungeonLayout = dungeonLayout + roomTypes[randint(0,4)]`